# Grails can't find integration test unless I do a grails clean

Tags: grails, integration-testing

Attempt to run an integration test throws a null exception unless I do a grails clean.

I execute the sequence of commands below

```
> grails
> test-app ShowIn  // throws NullPointer exception
> clean
> test-app ShowIn  // now the test magically passes
```

I changed nothing in the code during the sequence of commands.

I am running grails 2.3.7, groovy 2.2.0 and jvm 1.6.0_35.

More detailed output below:

```
| Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 0m 0s
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Compiling 1 source files....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Error Fatal error running tests: null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in C:\mroot\gplay\projects\ShowAdapterPOC4\target\test-reports
| Error Error running script test-app ShowIn: java.lang.NullPointerException (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
grails> exit
| Goodbye

| Application cleaned.

| Enter a script name to run. Use TAB for completion:
grails> test-app ShowIn
| Compiling 10 source files
| Compiling 16 source files.....
| Compiling 16 source files....
| Compiling 16 source files....
| Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
2014-04-21 19:44:57,432 [main] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  -
    /* criteria query */ select
        this_.ShowId as ShowId0_0_
    from
        Shows this_
| Completed 1 integration test, 0 failed in 0m 0s
| Tests PASSED - view reports in C:\mroot\gplay\projects\ShowAdapterPOC4\target\test-reports
grails>


Here's the test


package showadapterpoc4



import spock.lang.*

import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec

class ShowInSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
//class ShowInSpec extends Specification{

    ShowInCongress showInCongress

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "find shows in congress db"() {
        setup:
            def shows = ShowInCongress.list()
        expect:
            shows.size() > 0
    }
}
```

Unit tests work fine every time, but integration tests don't get found unless do the grails clean.

The test is hitting a domain class.  Do I have to do a clean every time I change a domain class?

What could I be doing wrong?  How can I avoid doing a grails clean every time I need to run an integration test?

Comment: How does the integration test look like? Is it a spock spec? If yes, does it inherit `Specification` or `IntegraionSpec`?

Comment: Specification - I'm pretty sure I used grails to generate the spec.  What's the package for integration spec?

Comment: should be under `test/integration` and extend `IntegrationSpec`

Comment: Created another integration test using command "create-integration-test ShowIn2".  It created a Specification sub-class in test/integration.  I changed the sub-class to IntegrationSpec.  Still need to do the grails clean.  I think this is due to the class testing a domain class and for some reason I need to do a grails clean after a make a change to the class.  I updated question accordingly.

Comment: I think its time to look at the integration spec. Can you share that as well?

Comment: How is `ShowInCongress` table populated in test environment?

Comment: Interesting question.  Why do you ask.  It is an existing sqlserver db.

Comment: It is beginning to look like if I change a domain object. I have to do a grails clean.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes I highly doubt that is the problem. Test environment generally use in memory db so that the setup can be cleaned immediately after test execution. Try to change the datasource to h2 in test environment and then setup mock data in test for `ShowInCongress`, then check if you see a change in behavior.